# call jquery function on the active class with event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call a function to add class `hover` to a link on the event when the carousel slide has the class `active`. The active class iterates over each item, toggling on and off. However the event handler i chose `on()` is not triggering the function to happen. How can i add the class when the item is active?

```
<div class="carousel">
    <div class="item"><a id="link1"></a></div>
    <div class="item"><a id="link2"></a></div>
    <div class="item active"><a id="link3"></a></div>
</div>


// if slide active, add class hover to the link
var test = jQuery('.hover');
function linkHover(){
  if(jQuery('.item.active').length != 0){
  jQuery('#link3').addClass('hover');
  }
};

jQuery(test).on( 'trigger', linkHover );
```

Comment: in `var test = jQuery('.hover');` you `jQuery` in `jQuery(test).on( 'trigger', linkHover );` no need `jQuery`

Comment: the trigger handler is never called because there was no element with class "hover" to attach to initially.

Comment: What is the event that adds the "active" class to the slide? If you have access to that you can set the "hover" class in there. There is no "trigger" event you can listen to.

Comment: maybe you could just target the a using css mate doing it like this `.item.active a{
 your css rules
}`..

Comment: @elfan ah i see, should i just use on() to listen to the event without the extra parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your making this more difficult than it needs to be. There should be a function that is called to switch the slide on the carousel. Inside that function just add:

```
$('.item').each(function() {
  $(this).removeClass('hover');
  $('.item.active').addClass('hover');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// if slide active, add class hover to the link
var test = $('.active');
function linkHover(){
  if($('.item.active').length != 0){
  $('#link3').addClass('hover');
  }
};
linkHover();
```

```css
.hover{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel">
    <div class="item"><a id="link1"></a></div>
    <div class="item"><a id="link2"></a></div>
    <div class="item active"><a id="link3">1</a></div>
</div>
```

Try like this